# Why do I have to finish the prologue to get online if I've already beaten the game?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I have already beaten GTA 5, and it was working fine. I was able to play online with friends without any difficulty.  A random error while joining a session caused me to go back to solo play, and when I attempted to go online from the pause menu, it said I have to finish the prologue.

I have already beaten the game, so I'm not certain why I should I have to finish the prologue.  Can anyone explain this, and is there a solution to this?  I would really like to be able to play online, again.

Comment: You may have selected a different save device.

Answer (score 2):

When this happens, you should manually load the save file where you have completed the game, and then attempt to reconnect to multiplayer. This should solve the problem.